# Height Responsive Joomla Custom HTML Module

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, media-queries, joomla3.0

Is is possible to have a custom html module that always fills the screen for all viewports?

I basically want to have a single Custom HTML module with a frame around it that will adapt to each viewport without any blank space below it.

I'm guessing it would have to be a piece of Java Script, but don't know what to search for, as I have just a basic understanding of jQuery. bootstrap, and Media Queries.

Thanks in advance for any help you can be.

Answer (score 0):

Mate, it's easier than you thought, just like this :

```
div {
    position:fixed !important;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
   }
```

Pure css, simple solution but works !

Comment: Thanks. Just want to make sure I get this. Let's say I wanted to put a photo in the module and have the div class called "div1".

I'd put this in the module: <div class="div1"><img src="images/photo.png" /></div>


   } and this in the template.css file: .div {
    position:fixed !important;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0; Have I go this right?

Comment: yep, almost there, just in your css file,  do this: div.div1 {position:fixed !important; position:absolute; top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;}

Comment: Thanks @Kevin Simple for your patient help on this. I think I've almost got it, but can't get it to work in the template we're planning on using. I know just enough to be dangerous and it looks like there's some line in this template that is overriding "position: absolute" but I can't figure out what it is. This is the link to the site: [link] (http://energywitness.com/test/).

What am I missing?